# @Input() value not defined in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I'm trying to get **isActivated** from an @Input() tweets. But When I want to store the **isActivated** to a variable this error comes up: **Tweet is not defined**. and Here's my code:( And sorry for my English too)

```
export class SingleTweetComponent { 
    @Input() tweet;
    isActivated = tweet.isActivated;
    likeButton($event){
        this.tweet.totalLikes = this.tweet.totalLikes - 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because tweet is not defined when you're trying to use it. At the time of computing properties **you don't have input data yet**.

To fix that you can take it in `OnInit` hook of the component:

```
export class SingleTweetComponent { 
    @Input() tweet;

    ngOnInit() {
      this.isActivated = this.tweet.isActivated;
    }

    likeButton($event) {
      this.tweet.totalLikes = this.tweet.totalLikes - 1;
    }
}
```